# Why does changing the step size in my Binomial Tree changes the final stock prices so much?

Tags: binomial-tree, quants, convertible-bond

I am trying to price a convertible bond by using a binomial tree. For this, I wrote a binomial tree for the stock price. I noticed that changing the step size (timesteps), changes the final value of my stock prices significantly. Intuitively this is wrong as the up and down movements should be scaled accordingly. I can imagine this will also change the price of the convertible bond.

I thought setting $u = \text{e}^{\sigma\sqrt{dt}}$ would do the trick. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import math as math

S0 = 100 #Initial stock price
T = 5 #Maturity
timesteps = 16 #Amount of steps in the three
dt = T/timesteps #Step size
sigma = 0.28 #Vol
r = 0.01 #Interest rate
N = 300 #Notional amount (for convertible bond)
kappa = N/S0 #Conversion rate (for convertible bond)
c = 0.05 #Coupomn rate (for convertible bond)

u = np.exp(sigma*math.sqrt(dt))
d = 1/u
p = (np.exp(r*dt)-d)/(u-d)


S = np.zeros((timesteps,timesteps))
for i in range(timesteps):
    for j in range(timesteps):
        S[j,i] = S0*(u**(i-j))*(d**j)

S = np.triu(S)
```

Comment: I think your computation of $dt$ is incorrect. Note that applying $u$ $n$ times leads to $\exp (\sigma n \sqrt{dt})$ which, unless I'm wrong, should be equivalent to $\exp (\sigma \sqrt{T})$, i.e., $n \sqrt{dt} = \sqrt{T}$, rather than $n dt = T$. I haven't checked in detail, but everything else seems fine.

Comment: What is significantly? What values of timesteps did you try?

Comment: Two timesteps give a range of 64 - 155, three timesteps 48 - 206 and 30 timesteps 3 - 2752. It doesn't converge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only got one minor bug, but let me explain why the range increases.

Let us denote $n:=timesteps$, then

1. **You are looping one iteration too little** when filling your $S$ matrix array, causing you to have S(T-dt) and not S(T) as terminal values. This is because you are not accounting for your starting position, i.e. you need $1+n$ iterations in each dimension.

```python
...
S = np.zeros((1+timesteps, 1+timesteps)) # Include starting position too (S0).
for i in range(S.shape[1]):
    for j in range(S.shape[0]):
        S[j,i] = S0*(u**(i-j))*(d**j)

S = np.triu(S)
```

2. **The range of possible values of $S(T)$ does correctly increase with $n$**. The range is given by $[S_0 d^n, S_0 u^n] = [S_0 e^{-\sigma\sqrt{nT}}, S_0 e^{\sigma\sqrt{nT}}]$. Note that while the range increases, the probability for ending at these extreme values decreases. In fact, according to the Central Limit Theorem, in the limit as $n\to \infty$ the binomial distribution will become the continuous log-Normal distribution, which indeed has infinite positive support $(0,+\infty)$.
3. **What the CRR binomial model ensures is that the mean and variance of the discrete binomial model matches those of the continuous model**. The mean of the stock will match exactly for any $n$, whereas the variance will asymptotically approach the continuous case. The reason for the variance not being exactly matched for any $n$ is that when finding the parameter $u$ by matching the variance, [approximations were made](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ejryanwang/courses/Financial%20Computation%20or%20Financial%20Engineering%20(graduate%20level)/FE_Ch04%20Binomial%20Tree%20Model.pdf) by only keeping first-order terms in a Taylor series expansion.

```python
# ====================================================
# === Compare moments to the continuous exact ones ===
# ====================================================

from scipy import stats as stats

# Binomial model for number of down moves
pd = 1-p
dist = stats.binom(n=timesteps, p=pd)

# Stock terminal mean and variance E[S(T)/S0] and V[S(T)/S0]
# 1st moment for S(T)
bin_m1 = dist.expect(lambda k: S[k.astype(int),-1]/S0)
# 2nd moment for S(T)
bin_m2 = dist.expect(lambda k: (S[k.astype(int),-1]/S0)**2)
# Var[S_T] = E[S_T^2] - E[S_T]^2
bin_var = bin_m2 - bin_m1**2
print(f'Binomial Model: E[S/S0]={bin_m1:.4f}, V[S/S0]={bin_var:.4f}')

# Continuous S(T) moments, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion#Properties
gbm_m1 = np.exp(r*T)
gbm_var = np.exp(2*r*T)*(np.exp(sigma**2*T)-1)
gbm_m2 = gbm_var + gbm_m1**2
print(f'Continuous GBM: E[S/S0]={gbm_m1:.4f}, V[S/S0]={gbm_var:.4f}')
```

Binomial Model: E[S/S0]=1.0513, V[S/S0]=0.5218

Continuous GBM: E[S/S0]=1.0513, V[S/S0]=0.5304

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.